# Using gsub to remove names and codes when we have multiple special character's

Tags: r

I have a string which I want to use a gsub to get out the name and the country code of each person, I think I'm close to being abl to solve it but the square brackets are causing me issues at the end of the string.

```
 mstring = 'name1=\"Bloggs, Joe[[UK\" name2=\"Brian Williams, Joe[AA] [[USA\"'
```

What I'm looking to achieve

```
mydat
name                  place
Bloggs, Joe           UK
Brian Williams, Joe   USA
```

I've been able to get out name 1 but struggling with getting out name 2 due to the extra set of square brackets. For name 1 I have used the following to get the name, just unable to get to the country and name 2. I though if I added a '?' to the '\[.*' part of the gsub this would look for any '[' rather than just the last one?

```
gsub(".*name1=\"([^\"]+) \\[.*", "\\1", mystring)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is in a slightly irritating format. It looks like it it is  the (garbled?) key-value pair output of some other software. It would be more robust to export it in a different format. However, if that is not possible, this should do it:

```r
mstring |>
  # Split rows from each other on \" 
  strsplit("\"\\s") |>
  # Split name from country on [[
  lapply(\(x) strsplit(x, "[[", fixed = TRUE) 
  ) |>
  unlist(recursive=FALSE) |>
  # Clean up the strings a little bit
  lapply(\(x) trimws(
    gsub("name\\d+=\"|\\[.+\\]|\"", "", x)
  )
  ) |>
  # Bind into a data frame and set names
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, args = _) |>
  setNames(c("name", "place"))
      
#                  name place
# 1         Bloggs, Joe    UK
# 2 Brian Williams, Joe   USA
```